# Property of a plane domain in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

A plane domain $D$ has the property that each point $z$ of $C \setminus D$ is contained in some unbounded, connected subset $A_z$ of $C \setminus D$.  Prove that $D$ is simply connected.

A domain is an open connected set.

A domain $D$ is said to be simply connected if every closed, piecewise smooth path is homologous to 0 in $D$.

My first idea was to consider a point $z_0 \in C\setminus D$.  Then $z_0 \in A_{z_0}$. This means that for any path $\gamma \in D$ we have $n(\gamma, z_0)=0$.  I'm not sure where to go from here, and I'm also worried since I barely used any of the assumptions.

Comment: Let $D$ be the union of the unit disk centered at $-2$ and the unit disk centered at $2$.  $D$ is clearly disconnected, but $\mathbb{C} \setminus D$ is both unbounded and connected.  What are you missing in the definition or problem statement?

Comment: A domain $D$ is a open, connected set.  So your example doesn't work.

Comment: Ah.  A definition.  Are open, connected sets bounded?

Comment: Yes, at least the ones I keep thinking about are.

Comment: Is the set $-1 < \Re(z) < 1$ open and connected?

Comment: I'm assuming that $\R(z)$ means real part of $z$?  If so, that's a band that is symmetric about the y-axis.  It's connected, open, and not bounded.

Comment: Do you believe in the 1-point compactification of $\mathbb{C}$?  If so, does this connect all the $A_z$ through the point at infinity?  (They're incident to it since they're all unbounded.)

Comment: If so, the boundary of $D$ is homeomorphic to a circle on the Riemann sphere...

Comment: What you are discussing is far beyond the scope of what I've studied so far in Complex.

Comment: What sorts of tools are you getting to?

Comment: The most advance tool I have is the discussion of cycles and the global cauchy integration formula/theorem.

Comment: If there were a bounded connected piece of $\mathbb{C} \setminus D$, call it $B$, and a $z_0 \in B$, then there would be a path in $D$ (since $D$ is connected) completely encircling $z_0$.  This loop would not contract to 0 because it cannot contract through $B$, nor can it contract through infinity to collapse "on the other side".  For $A_z$s as given, any such loop must pass through the point at infinity, which they cannot.  The set of all paths in $D$ therefore contains no uncontractible loops.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand.  We haven't delved into discussions of paths going to infinity.  So we suppose to the contrary that abounded $B$ would exist and that $z_0$ is in $B$.  Then we can find a path $\gamma$ in $D$ such that $z_0$ is interior to this path.  I'm not sure how to incorporate the unboundedness of $A_{z_0}$.

Comment: If $A_{z_0}$ is unbounded, there is a path connecting $z_0$ to infinity lying in $A_{z_0}$.  Can the loop cross this path?

Comment: Well no.  So basically it's as if there is a path just jetting out in one direction since $A_{z_0}$ is connected.

Comment: Yup.  Is that enough to get you rolling?  I.e., there are no loops in $D$, since those would encircle a $z_0$.  But that $z_0$ is connected to $\infty$ by a path in $A_{z_0}$ which would be crossed by the assumed loop, so the loop does not exist.  Thus every loop in $D$ is contractible to $0$.

Comment: We haven't mentioned contractability.  But this is enough to get me started.  Thanks.

Comment: The statement you are trying to prove is equivalent to the Jordan curve theorem.  It cannot be proved using the elementary geometric arguments described in the comments, but there is probably a way to do it using the Cauchy integral theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A domain $D$ is said to be simply connected if every closed, piecewise smooth path is homologous to $0$ in $D$.

That means your first idea is effectively the solution, you just need to recognise that, and write it up properly.

Let $\gamma$ be a piecewise smooth closed path in $D$. Then for every $z_0\notin D$, the winding number $n(\gamma,z)$ is constant on the connected set $A_{z_0}$. Since $A_{z_0}$ is unbounded, there are points $w\in A_{z_0}$ with $\lvert n(\gamma,w)\rvert < 1$. [I leave out a few steps now ...] Therefore $\gamma$ is homologous to $0$ in $D$. Since $\gamma$ was arbitrary, $D$ is simply connected.